# Get the real-time web design preview from the browser

Tags: real-time

Assume that I have two monitors assigned to my pc. Now I want to get the preview of a web site while coding it. Is there anyway to do this?
eg:- Do the coding from sublime text from a one monitor and the **meantime** watch the output from the Firefox web browser.

Comment: "Visual Web Developer" is a Microsoft program. Does that tag have anything to do with your question?

Comment: Forgive me. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [live.js](http://livejs.com/) for this more than once. It can work either as a bookmarklet or embedded on your page, and it works in any browser as it's not an extension. Also requires no other software to work.

The downside is it that it will flood your developer tools with HEAD requests every second or so to determine when to reload things. That's the cost of not having to install external software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LiveReload](https://github.com/dz0ny/LiveReload-sublimetext2) plugin for SublimeText. It listens for changes to your code files and updates them in the browser in real time.

Also, do not forget to add the respective [browser extension](http://livereload.com/extensions/). That should save you from adding any scripts into your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) ( with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) depends on which generator you want to use ).